# aplay read error when editing code in main

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

I have a file named experiment.cpp. In the main function, I extract the mono channel and downsample it. I was able to run experiment.cpp and it performed the process as described. However, I wanted to put mono processing in a single file outside of experiment.cpp. Just by putting the mono processing part of the main function code in comments, I got this "aplay: read_header:2834:read error" error. I'd like to know why I got this error and how to solve it.
[image]

```
#include "dy4.h"
#include "filter.h"
#include "fourier.h"
#include "genfunc.h"
#include "iofunc.h"
#include "logfunc.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
//int main(){
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int mode = 0;
    if(argc < 2){
        std::cerr << " Operating in default mode 0" << std::endl;
    } else if (argc == 2){
        mode = atoi(argv[1]);
        if (mode != 1){
            std::cerr << "Wrong mode" << mode << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }else{
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "or" <<std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " 1" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    int rf_Fs = 2.4e6;
    int rf_Fc = 100e3;
    int rf_taps = 50;
    int rf_decim = 10;

  int rf1_Fs = 2.5e6;
    int mode0_Fs = 240e3;
    int mode0_decim = 5;
    int mode0_Fc =16e3;
    int mode0_taps = 50;

    int expand_rate = 24;
    int mode1_Fs = 250e3*expand_rate;
    int mode1_Fc = mode0_Fc;
    int mode1_decim = 125;
    int mode1_taps = 1250;

  std::vector<float> rf_coeff;
    std::vector<float> rf1_coeff;
    std::vector<float> mode0_coeff;
    std::vector<float> mode1_coeff;

    impulseResponseLPF(rf_Fs, rf_Fc, rf_taps, rf_coeff);
    impulseResponseLPF(rf1_Fs, rf_Fc, rf_taps, rf1_coeff);
    impulseResponseLPF(mode0_Fs, mode0_Fc, mode0_taps,mode0_coeff);
    impulseResponseLPF(mode1_Fs, mode1_Fc, mode1_taps,mode1_coeff);
    int BLOCK_SIZE = 1024*rf_decim*mode0_decim*2;
    std::vector<float> state_i_lpf_100k;
    state_i_lpf_100k.resize(rf_taps-1,0.0);
    std::vector<float> state_q_lpf_100k;
    state_q_lpf_100k.resize(rf_taps-1,0.0);
    std::vector<float> state_phase;
    state_phase.resize(2,0.0);
    std::vector<float> mode0_lpf_16k;
    std::vector<float> mode1_lpf_16k;
    mode0_lpf_16k.resize(mode0_taps-1,0.0);
    mode1_lpf_16k.resize(mode1_taps-1,0.0);
    std::vector<float> temp_I;
    temp_I.resize(BLOCK_SIZE/2,0.0);
    std::vector<float> temp_Q;
    temp_Q.resize(BLOCK_SIZE/2,0.0);
    std::vector<float> i_filt;
  std::vector<float> q_filt;
    std::vector<float> mode0_filt;
    std::vector<float> mode1_filt;
    std::vector<float> i_ds;
  std::vector<float> q_ds;
    std::vector<float> mode0_block;
    mode0_block.resize(BLOCK_SIZE/rf_decim/mode0_decim,0.0);
    std::vector<float> mode1_block;
    mode1_block.resize(BLOCK_SIZE*13/rf_decim/mode1_decim,0.0);
    std::vector<float> fm_demod;
    std::vector<float> exp_fm_demod;
    int mode0_data_size;
    std::vector<short int> mode0_data;
    mode0_data.resize(BLOCK_SIZE,0.0);
    int mode1_data_size;
    std::vector<short int> mode1_data;
    mode1_data.resize(BLOCK_SIZE,0.0);
    std::vector<float> block_data(BLOCK_SIZE);
    //mono_processing() commented out
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please share your code - thanks.

Comment: Impossible to provide a quality answer with this little information. Consider constructing a [mre], and if the process of making the MRE doesn't reveal the mistake to you in all it's buggy glory, update the question and add the MRE.